# npm install on raspbian takes much time

Tags: linux, node.js, raspberry-pi, npm-install

*Some specs*: Raspbian on Raspberry Pi 2

*Story*: I cloned a repo from GitHub to my Raspberry Pi 2, installed node and ran npm install in the project directory.

The problem now is that the process takes about 20 minutes (after that I'm aborting with ctrl+c). npm loggs some warnings and stucks.

Running the same command on my Windows pc takes maybe 2 or 3 minutes (updating goes way faster of course).

Is this normal behavior on raspbian? If there is no solution I would consider to transfer the files with SFTP.

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable progressbar, it can helps:

```
npm set progress=false
npm install
```

Here is some explanations: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/11283